Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem in Flutter SQFlite
I encountered this error while working on my Flutter application. It seems to be related to the platform operation in Dart. The error message suggests that there is an unsupported operation related to retrieving the operating system information.
I'm using Flutter with the sqflite package for local database operations. The error occurs during the initialization of the database. Here's the relevant part of the stack trace:
at get operatingSystem (platform_impl.dart:56:40)
at get operatingSystem (platform.dart:83:44)
at get isAndroid (platform.dart:156:50)
at sqflite_database_factory.dart:9:16
at get sqfliteDatabaseFactory (sqflite_database_factory.dart:16:44)


Here is The Full Error (Edge Console) :
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:297:3)
    at _Platform._operatingSystem (io_patch.dart:244:5)
    at get operatingSystem (platform_impl.dart:56:40)
    at get operatingSystem (platform.dart:83:44)
    at desc.get [as operatingSystem] (operations.dart:1293:8)
    at get isAndroid (platform.dart:156:50)
    at desc.get [as isAndroid] (operations.dart:1293:8)
    at sqflite_database_factory.dart:9:16
    at get sqfliteDatabaseFactory (sqflite_database_factory.dart:16:44)
    at desc.get [as sqfliteDatabaseFactory] (operations.dart:1293:8)
    at database$._$AppDatabaseBuilder.new.build (database.g.dart:46:17)
    at build.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:127:5)
    at database$._$AppDatabaseBuilder.new.build (database.g.dart:44:28)
    at main$ (main.dart:55:47)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at async_patch.dart:45:50
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1661:54)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:162:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:838:44)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:867:13)
    at [_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:643:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:713:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:181:7


I expected the application to initialize the database without any errors. Interestingly, the project works seamlessly when installed on an Android mobile device. However, when accessed via web view, this error occurs consistently.
Flutter Version: 3.19.6
Dart Version: 3.3.4
Platform: Android mobile device (Works), Web view (Error occurs)
Relevant Code Snippet: my database.dart
// database.dart

// required package imports
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:pill_pal/entities/medicine.dart';
import 'package:pill_pal/entities/reminder.dart';
import 'package:pill_pal/entities/reminderCheck.dart';
import 'package:pill_pal/util/converters/ColorIntConverter.dart';
import 'package:pill_pal/util/converters/DateTimeConverter.dart';
import 'package:pill_pal/util/converters/ListStringConverter.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqflite;

import 'dao/medicine_dao.dart';
import 'dao/reminder_check_dao.dart';
import 'dao/reminder_dao.dart';

part 'database.g.dart'; // the generated code will be there

@TypeConverters([DateTimeConverter, ListStringConverter,  ColorIntConverter])
@Database(version: 1, entities: [Medicine, Reminder, ReminderCheck])
abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
  MedicineDao get medicineDao;
  ReminderDao get reminderDao;
  ReminderCheckDao get reminderCheckDao;
}

Future<AppDatabase> initDb() async {


  final database = await $FloorAppDatabase
      .databaseBuilder('app_database.db')
      .build();

  return database;
}


This is my first ever Stackoverflow post , i apologize for any mistake that you encountered in this post.

Have you checked https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi_web
